# TSLint is throwing 'error TS2459: Module '"@azure/core-tracing"' declares 'Span' locally, but it is not exported.' and other errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, azure-ai

I have no idea where to start with fixing this error. The output doesn't really tell me a whole lot except that it sounds like something is wrong with the '@azure/ai-text-analytics' install. I've `npm uninstall`'d it twice and reinstalled it twice. It's giving the same error so I guess it isn't the install?

The full error I get:

```
node_modules/@azure/core-http/types/latest/src/createSpanLegacy.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2459: Module '"@azure/core-tracing"' declares 'Span' locally, but it is not exported.

1 import { Span } from "@azure/core-tracing";
           ~~~~

  node_modules/@azure/core-tracing/types/core-tracing.d.ts:6:10
    6 import { Span } from '@opentelemetry/api';
               ~~~~
    'Span' is declared here.

node_modules/@azure/core-http/types/latest/src/webResource.d.ts:9:23 - error TS2305: Module '"@azure/core-tracing"' has no exported member 'Context'.

9 import { SpanOptions, Context } from "@azure/core-tracing";
                        ~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

Obviously none of those files are my own code so I don't have anything else to show that I can think of.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?

Comment: Oh no. Sorry I'm just now seeing this. I did get help with this from Microsoft. The problem was with my tsconfig.json file. Here is what I have now:

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received help on GitHub support. Here's the [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/75845) to the answer.

> I did more debugging and it looks like the TypeScript compiler is trying to build the d.ts files inside node_modules which is causing the build failure. Looks like using the paths option in your tsconfig.json file caused this issue and when I removed it, the project built just fine with core-http@1.2.4.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I mistakenly used the wrong path in from "/wrong/path".